# Changing state in componentDidMount doesn't lead to render in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm saving a `searchObject` from database to `localStorage` and redirecting to `/discover` onclick:

```
  modelInstance.getSearchFromDB(id).then((searchObject) => {
  console.log(searchObject);
  modelInstance.setSearchParams(searchObject); // Save search params to localStorage

  window.location.assign("/discover");
 })
```

In `discover.js`, I use the `searchObject` object:

```
class DiscoverContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            status: 'NULL',
            searchInput: ""
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      let searchObject = modelInstance.getSearchParams(); // function that gets search params and eliminates them from localStorage

      console.log("searchObject.query:");
      console.log(searchObject.query);

      if(searchObject){
        this.setState({
          status: "LOADED",
          searchInput: searchObject.query,
          positive: searchObject.positive,
          negative: searchObject.negative,
          total: searchObject.total,
          noOfNeutral: searchObject.noOfNeutral,
          until: searchObject.until,
          placeName: searchObject.location,

        });
      }
    }

render () {
  const { stepsEnabled, steps, initialStep} = this.state;

  }

    return (
        <div className="container-discover">
            <Search handleStatusChange={this.handleStatusChange} searchInput={this.state.searchInput}/>
        </div>

    );
```

As you can see, in `componentDidMount`, I'm setting `this.state.searchInput` to the searchObject value. My expectation is that this will lead to the new value being sent to the `Search` object in `render`, so that `Search` will send this value to its child `SearchInput`:

Search.js:

```
class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    var today = new Date();
    console.log("in Search:");
    console.log(props.searchInput);
    this.state = {
      searchSuggestion: 'Search for tweets here',
      anchorEl: null,
      page: 0,
      placeName: "LOCATION", // === '' ? "LOCATION" : modelInstance.getPlaceName()
      placeOptions: modelInstance.getPlaceOptions(),
      searchInput: props.searchInput,
    }
  render(){
    return(
        <div className='search'>
          <Row id='searchInput'>
            <SearchInput handleInput={this.handleInput.bind(this)} searchInput={this.state.searchInput} searchSuggestion={this.state.searchSuggestion} page={1}/>
          </Row>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I output `searchObject.query` (you can see it in the code) in the `discover.js` file, and the right value is there. But, when I output `props.searchInput` in `Search'`, nothing is output. This seems to be because `Search.constructor` runs before `Discover.componentDidMount`. It feels like I'm going about this the wrong way. What is the right way of passing down state of a parent to a "grand-child"?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to copy the prop into the child's state, just reference the prop directly in `render`:

```
class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchSuggestion: 'Search for tweets here',
      anchorEl: null,
      page: 0,
      placeName: 'LOCATION',
      placeOptions: modelInstance.getPlaceOptions(),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <div className='search'>
          <Row id='searchInput'>
            <SearchInput
              handleInput={this.handleInput.bind(this)}
              searchInput={this.props.searchInput}
              searchSuggestion={this.state.searchSuggestion}
              page={1}
            />
          </Row>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```